# Tapping on a View to also change its sibling views

Tags: swift, swiftui

Within a VStack, I have 3 views. A view's selection and colour are toggled when tapping on them. I want the previously selected View to be deselected when selecting the next view.
The tapGesture is implemented in each view. I am not sure what is the best way to achieve this.
Thanks.
Here is the code sample:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var tile1 = Tile()
    @State var tile2 = Tile()
    @State var tile3 = Tile()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TileView(tile: tile1 )
            TileView(tile: tile2 )
            TileView(tile:tile3 )
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct Tile: Identifiable, Equatable{
    var id:UUID = UUID()
    var isSelected:Bool = false
}

struct TileView: View {
    
    @State var tile:Tile
    
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
            .fill( tile.isSelected ? Color.red : Color.yellow )
            .frame(height: 100)
            .padding()
            .onTapGesture {
                tile.isSelected.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could do an observable view model that would toggle selection. Also, your tile view doesn’t need the tile as state and you are passing same tile to all 3.

Comment: Corrected code as you pointed out, however that would not change the issue. As I understand to use an ObservableObject you need to use a class while I was trying to keep to struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to relate the 3 tiles somehow. An `Array` is an option. Then once they are related you can change the selection at that level.

```
extension Array where Element == Tile{
    ///Marks the passed `tile` as selected and deselects other tiles.
    mutating func select(_ tile: Tile) {
        for (idx, t) in self.enumerated(){
            if t.id == tile.id{
                self[idx].isSelected.toggle()
            }else{
                self[idx].isSelected = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can change your views to use the new function.

```
struct MyTileListView: View {
    @State var tiles: [Tile] = [Tile(), Tile(), Tile()]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(tiles) { tile in
                TileView(tile: tile, onSelect: {
                    //Use the array to select the tile
                    tiles.select(tile)
                })
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct TileView: View {
    //@State just create a copy of the tile `@Binding` is a two-way connection if needed
    let tile:Tile
    ///Called when the tile is selected
    let onSelect: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
            .fill(tile.isSelected ? Color.red : Color.yellow)
            .frame(height: 100)
            .padding()
            .onTapGesture {
                onSelect()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked as expected. However I was thinking if there is a clever SwiftUI way of linking sibling views together. But I guess not.

Comment: @reza23 no this wouldn’t fall into something SwiftUI would do directly. SwiftUI deals with UI, managing model data isn’t within scope.